# Rspec: mock update_attributes in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mocha.js, stub

I'm pretty new in testing rails applications. Now, I'm learning how to mock methods.

I have method that changes password in my User model:

```
  def change_password(user, pass)
    self.update_attributes(user) if self.password_hash == self.encrypt_password(pass)
  end
```

All I want to do is to mock method update_attributes. To do this, I wrote a test:

```
let (:user) {FactoryGirl.build(:user)}
subject{user}
...
describe "#change_password" do
  before {user.save}
    context "when old password doesn't match" do
      it "should not update password" do
        user.should_not_receive(:update_attributes)
        user.change_password(user,"invalid")
      end
    end
  end
```

But when I run it, I am getting error:

```
NoMethodError:
       undefined method `should_not_receive' for #<User:0x0000000455daf8>
```

ALSO, I've tried to mock update_attributes method like this:

```
user.change_password.should_not_receive(:update_attributes)
```

and I've got another mistake:

```
ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (0 for 2)
```

And I couldn't find any manual of how to mock methods inside methods with attributes.

Could anybody help me with my problem,please?

Answer (score 0):

To use `should_receive` method u need to set `config.mock_with :rspec` but I've set `config.mock_with :mocha`. So I should use `expects` instead of `should_receive`.